# add job to queue Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, queue, jobs

i got a problem when execute my queue. Job doesnt work.

.env:

```
QUEUE_CONNECTION=database_name
```

Job:

```
use App\Models\ProfessorSuscriptionHistory;

class CheckSuscription implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public function __construct()
    {

    }
    public function handle()
    {
        $suscription_history = new ProfessorSuscriptionHistory();
        $suscription_history->user_id = 13;
        $suscription_history->type = 'trimestral';
        $suscription_history->pdf = 'test.pdf';
        $suscription_history->ended_at = Carbon::now()->addMonth(3);
        $suscription_history->save();
    }
}
```

My controller what dispatch a Job

```
use App\Jobs\CheckSuscription;

class TestController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        CheckSuscription::dispatch()->onQueue('processing');
    }
}
```

i used command `php artisan queue:work` and `php artisan queue:listen` but nothing appear in cmd. i migrated jobs to my db using `php artisan queue:table` and nothing appear in jobs table or failed_jobs table too. How can i fix that? thx!!

Comment: Any errors? Did you run `queue:table` and `migrate` after or before dispatching jobs?

Comment: Yes @geertjanknapen, i got the tables generated.

Comment: And after that you retried dispatching the job and running the queue, yes?

There's no errors being shown or anything?

Answer (score 1):

Put your `QUEUE_CONNECTION=database_name` to just `QUEUE_CONNECTION=database` you dont put the database name you just tell Laravel to use a certain queue. database, redis ...

[Queue Connection](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queues#database)